# How to unregister a customised file extension on Mac

Tags: macos

In my Mac app, I have registered two file extension with specific icon image, when it's first opened, everything went well.

After recent update. One of the file extension has been removed, and another one used a new icon instead of previous icon.

But after opening the new app, seems OS still remembered the old plist config, I tried to restart launch service, but didn't work.

What should I do to reset it? By code or by terminal. Both are OK.

Comment: Google "reset LaunchServices".

Comment: @Willeke As I stated in the question, this didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread restart as restart instead of reset.